# setIndoorEnabled , level switcher in google maps Api v3 for HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is the setIndoorEnabled function for Indoor maps available via the Google Maps API V3 that I can use in a website instead of the android api which I believe would not work on a site.

Here is the link to the function in Android API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map?hl=it#indoor_maps

I am trying to use this to show indoor floor plans. Basically asking if there is a way to enable this in Google maps via the Javascript V3 api?

Success condition would enable to see the level switcher when the maps is zoomed in.

Comment: 1. It is `setIndoorEnabled` and not *setIndoorMaps*. 2. Did you find it in the Javascript API v3 reference? No. Does that answer your question? I hope it does.

Comment: Updated the question to address this comment

Answer (score 0):

The Indoor Maps are available in Google Maps Android API and iOS SDK, but not int he Google Maps API JS. Please star [this issue tracker FR](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35819848) to get notified when this gets implemented

There is no way to programatically check if a given location is "indoor enabled". The closest you can to such a check is the getFocusedBuilding function which will get the current focused building or null if no building is focused (implying there is no indoor map)